# Fill first Row after group by in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, group-by

Here is my sample data

```
  COMM_AGENT_ID     ADP  CHANNEL    AMOUNT_TIER  SUM_AMOUNT_TIER    SALES_MGR
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
       AC028        3583  HP                 3         NULL          NULL
       AC028        3583  HP                 3         NULL          NULL
       AC028        3583  HP                 3         NULL          NULL
       AC028        3583  HP                 3         NULL          NULL
       AC029        3583  JK                 3         NULL          NULL
       AC029        3583  JK                 3         NULL          NULL
       AC029        3583  JK                 3         NULL          NULL
       AC029        3583  JK                 3         NULL          NULL
```

I want my output in this format:

```
   COMM_AGENT_ID    ADP  CHANNEL    AMOUNT_TIER  SUM_AMOUNT_TIER    SALES_MGR
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------
       AC028        3583  HP                 3         9             ABC
       AC028        3583  HP                 3         NULL          NULL
       AC028        3583  HP                 3         NULL          NULL
       AC028        3583  HP                 3         NULL          NULL
       AC029        3583  JK                 3         9             PQR
       AC029        3583  JK                 3         NULL          NULL
       AC029        3583  JK                 3         NULL          NULL
       AC029        3583  JK                 3         NULL          NULL
```

Here `abc` and `pqr` are the name  that will be filled in only first row and 9 is the some of group by on COMM_AGENT_ID and ADP.

I have done by using CTE on row_number. I have generated the row number on `partition by ADP,comm_agent_ID` and updating the value `where SRNO=1`

And it is working but output is not in correct format.

My current output:

```
     COMM_AGENT_ID  ADP  CHANNEL    AMOUNT_TIER  SUM_AMOUNT_TIER    SALES_MGR
     ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       AC028        3583  HP                 3         NULL          NULL
       AC028        3583  HP                 3         NULL          NULL
       AC028        3583  HP                 3         9             ABC
       AC028        3583  HP                 3         NULL          NULL
       AC029        3583  JK                 3         NULL          NULL
       AC029        3583  JK                 3         NULL          NULL
       AC029        3583  JK                 3         9             PQR
       AC029        3583  JK                 3         NULL          NULL
```

it is not on first row.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the current code you have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 SELECT COMM_AGENT_ID,ADP,CHANNEL,SUM_AMOUNT_TIER,SALES_MGR 
 FROM GSM G 
 ORDER BY COMM_AGENT_ID,adp,SUM_AMOUNT_TIER DESC
```

Comment: Wow... Took my accepted answer away to post your own. Comical.

Comment: All that for a badge, eh? Hahaha

Answer (score 0):

Your results are fine. Add an `ORDER BY SUM_AMOUNT_TIER DESC, COMM_AGENT_ID` and it will be "on the first row"

Comment: i used it but it should be like this ..COMM_AGENT_ID,adp,SUM_AMOUNT_TIER DESC

Comment: Awesome @Ramdeoangh